# PHPStorm on ubuntu drag and drop cuts instead of moving

Tags: ide, phpstorm-2016.3

I have drag and drop enabled in the editor settings however when I highlight text and then try and move it the editor seems to perform the cut but not the paste. I can manually paste afterwards but it is really annoying.

Comment: Same on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that the plugin "Markdown Navigator" was causing the issue. With help from the vendor I identified and removed this plugin - which corrected the problem.